# jira: How do I put a text after a nested list?

Tags: jira

In Jira, how do I put a text after a nested list in the context of the current numbered top level list? I have problems with indentation and numbering.
Desired:

```
 1. one
    Text before nested list
        • List item
        • List item
    Text after nested list 
 2. two
```

Without empty line before "Text after nested list" I get wrong indent:

```
 1. one
    Text before nested list
        • List item
        • List item
        Text after nested list 
 2. two
```

With empty line I also have wrong number:

```
 1. one
    Text before nested list
        • List item
        • List item
 Text after nested list 
 1. two
```

Comment: That's a good question. If you have a Confluence 3.x instance handy you could experiment there but I suppose Preview does a good enough job. JIRA wiki rendering was a subset of Confluence originally, and now Confluence has ditched that markup in favor of XHTML I don't think there's much work done on it.

Comment: You are free to accept helpful answers or comment if there is anything unclear.  ;)

Comment: After about 2 hours of searching, I just gave up as it seems that there is no humane way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a work around like

```
# one {panel:borderStyle=none}
Text before nested list
* list item
* list item

Text after nestes list {panel}
# two
```

You apparently would get kind of additional line breaks around the panel (margin), but if that doesn't bother you, you're good to go.  :)

Comment: Lovely hack! Thanks for that!

Comment: With Confluence instance deployed at my $dayjob—it's v3.0.2—I had to defeat the non-default background color using `{panel:borderStyle=none|bgColor=transparent}`, and, sadly, border is still there—irrespective of the `borderStyle` setting; specifying `borderWidth=0` does not help either. Still, thanks for the hack!